# vagrant box aborted, can not up

Tags: vagrant

I got the error message from the command line:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/xenial64' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> default: available! You currently have version '20181102.0.0'. The latest is version
==> default: '20181122.1.0'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "8cb8ae85-050a-4bf2-8f8a-5b53bc002c24", "--natpf1", 
"delete", "ssh", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp3306", "--natpf1", "delete", 
"tcp443", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp5000", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp6379", "-- 
natpf1", "delete", "tcp7000", "--natpf1", "delete", "tcp80", "--natpf1", 
"delete", "tcp9000"]
```

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error 
(extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at
line 525 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

Can you help me ?

Sorry, i just stop the machine in visualbox and restart it . Everything just got right, i still don't know the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more in depth logs by using `$ vagrant up --debug` or if you would like to save it to a file `$ vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log`. Otherwise I would recommend making sure all VMs are stopped then run `$ vagrant reload --provision`. Also, the wonderful thing about this is you can just tear it down and start over very easily! :)